# Segoe UI Historic a non-displaying number

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, font-encodings

I have created a MWE of the (rare) font `Segoe UI Historic`. Number 13001 works (see in between A and B below) but one thousand
numbers after, at 14001 (see between B and C below), it displays an empty box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
 
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]
 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
A 
{\ngg\symbol{"13001}}
B
{\ngg\symbol{"14001}}
C 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
How do I compute the labeling in enumerate
**modulo 3** ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
 
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]
 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[ label=\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "14000+\value{enumi}}]

\item A 
\item {\ngg\symbol{"13001}}
\item B
\item {\ngg\symbol{"14001}}
\item C 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a why do you expect the font to have this glyph?

Comment: I would just like if the font had this glyph. I have a numbering of items in `\enumerate` environment and there are many of them. So there is no way to fix it and continue with numbering ?

Comment: there is imho no unicode glyph at position U+14000, that is somewhere between the egyptian and the athopian hieroglyphs. What symbol do you expect to get here?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK I happy with it that there is no symbol for large numbers. Bu please see the **EDIT**.

Comment: btw you are not 1000 numbers later. " means that the numbers are interpretated as hexadezimal numbers, so it  "1000 =  4096 decimal.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The first wrong position is 1071. Can I obtain the solution via. modulo operation ? How do I do that ?

Comment: look, could you first say which symbol you actually want? Your \symbol{"13001} prints the hieroglyph U+13001, where I have no idea what it represents or why you want to use it for numbering.

Comment: I want to use numberings from 1 to 1000 and then get back to 1 instead of 1001. I need for this a modulo operation from this `\value{enumi}` to `\value{enumi} modulo 1000` but I do not know the right syntax for this.

Comment: but which symbols do you want to use? letter? greek? russian? chinese? arbitrary flowers?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My `\ngg` font as declared in my MWE above: `\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]` The numeral corresponding to `\ngg` The letter just between A and B in my OQ: `{\ngg\symbol{"13001}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554346/how-do-i-make-item-labels-to-be-computed-modulo-4-to-see-it-on-a-small-examp) new question made more precise.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Dear Ulrike can you please have a look below [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554346/how-do-i-make-item-labels-to-be-computed-modulo-4-to-see-it-on-a-small-examp) yours answer ? I need further help.

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment so as answer. It is quite unclear yet which symbols you actually want to use so here some code to print out every glyph (the boxes means that the font doesn't have such a glyph) (you can naturally enlarge the number, hex 13000 is around 80000):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Seguihis.ttf}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn {14000} %choose number ....
{\makebox[1cm][l]{\char#1\textsubscript{#1}}\c_space_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554346/how-do-i-make-item-labels-to-be-computed-modulo-4-to-see-it-on-a-small-examp) new question made more precise.