# How do I make `\item` labels to be computed modulo 4 (to see it on a small example)

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, itemize

How do I make `\item` labels to be computed modulo 4 (to see it on a small example) .
Then I change it to modulo 1000 in my final project.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
 
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]
 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[ label=\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}]

\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13004}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13005}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13006}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13007}}
\item etc. 13000+i modulo 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I apologize for a small typo (in my intended modulo 4 operation) but the idea
should be clear.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to set custom enumii labels that cycle across items](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/237926)

Comment: @AlanMunn I cannot obtain a solution to my problem from your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example that can grow. But I didn't check if your font has 1000 consecutive glyphs starting from 13000, so it is quite possible that you will get missings glyphs somewhere in the middle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]

\usepackage{enumitem}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@moduloitem #1
  {
   \ngg
    \char
     \int_eval:n
      {
        \int_mod:nn{\int_use:c{#1}}{\modulolength}
        +
        \exp_args:No\int_from_hex:n{\modulostart}
      }
  }
\newcommand\moduloitem[1]{\@moduloitem{c@#1}}  
\newcommand\modulostart{13000}   %adapt
\newcommand\modulolength{3}      %adapt
\AddEnumerateCounter{\moduloitem}{\@moduloitem}{AA}
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[ label=\moduloitem*]

\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13004}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13005}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13006}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13007}}
\item etc. 13000+i modulo 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what roughly are you doing in between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` and also why you do not call `\makeatother` at the end ?

Comment: I don't call \makeatother as I constantly forget it. And in the expl3 I basically calculate the modulo (with int_mod) plus the 13000 converted from hex to decimal (with int_from_hex). There is no magic there.

Comment: I do not understand the syntactic sugar there. `Npn` `eval` `exp` `:nn` etc. Could you please give here a link to web explaining these commands ? I'm intersted in it.

Comment: search for expl3.pdf and interface3.pdf in your doc folder of your tex system.

Comment: Right, I have found these 2 in google. What's the difference between expl3.pdf and interface3.pdf roughly so that I can start reading the 2 manuals ?

Comment: in expl3.pdf you find that in 3.2.6 Functions: argument specifications and in section 4.  interface3.pdf has it in 1 Naming functions and variables.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, by your example, what you want is modulo 3, not 4. Here is an example making use of `enumitem`'s `\AddEnumerateCounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]
 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\def\historicCnt#1{\expandafter\@historicCnt\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@historicCnt#1{%
  \ifcase#10\or1\or2\or3%
  \else
    \expandafter\@historicCnt\expandafter{\numexpr#1-3\relax}%
  \fi
}

\AddEnumerateCounter{\historicCnt}{\@historicCnt}{XX}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\historicCnt*\relax}]

\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13004}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13005}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13006}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13007}}
\item etc. 13000+i modulo 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

A new latex3 flavored function `\iten_mod:nn` is defined, it accepts two integers `#1` and `#2`, and returns `#1 mod #2` if `(#1 mod #2) > 0`, otherwise `#2`. You can use it to accomplish "mod 1000" or similar tasks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]


\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% register \historicCnt as a new counter representation
\AddEnumerateCounter{\historicCnt}{\@historicCnt}{XX}

% define \historicCnt
\def\historicCnt#1{
  \expandafter\@historicCnt\csname c@#1\endcsname
}

\def\@historicCnt#1{
  \item_mod:nn {#1}{3}
}

% return (#1 mod #2) if (#1 mod #2) > 0 else #2
\cs_new:Nn \item_mod:nn
  {
    1 + \int_mod:nn {#1-1}{#2}
  }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\historicCnt*\relax}]

\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} and is such
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13004}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13005}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13006}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}} but is {\ngg\symbol{"13007}}
\item etc. 13000+i modulo 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works. But now, I cannot easily change to modulo 1000 as I thought. How can I do that ??

Comment: @user2925716 A general modulo function is added, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hook properly in `enumitem`. I used modulo 3, which is what you actually have in your example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
 
\newfontfamily\ngg{SegoeUIHistoric.ttf}[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.2]

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nggcounter}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \ngg
  \symbol
   {
    \int_eval:n { "13001 + \int_mod:nn { \value{#1} - 1 } { 3 } } % change here the modulus
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@nggcounter}[1]{#1}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\nggcounter}{\@nggcounter}{{\ngg\symbol{"13001}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\nggcounter*]

\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13002}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13003}}
\item this label should be {\ngg\symbol{"13001}}
\item etc. 13000+i modulo 3

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]